# Leaflet popupclose fuction is not reseting the map view as defined

Tags: leaflet

I have a Leaflet map that visualizes a bunch of features in a downtown area.  I am using popups to visualize additional information about each feature.

When the user closes the popup, I want the map to re-center to the original position and zoom level.  This should be supported using `popupclose` and `setview`.  However, this code does not seem to be working.  My script is below.

```
<script>

  var map = L.map('map', {minZoom: 15,}).setView([40.66,-73.6466], 17);

  L.tileLayer('http://basemaps.cartocdn.com/rastertiles/voyager/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png', {
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
  }).addTo(map);

/* Beginning of Feature Data in GeoJSON */

    var geojsonFeature = /* feature data omitted from post */

/* End of Feature Data in GeoJSON */

        L.geoJSON(geojsonFeature, {
            onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
              var picture;
                if (feature.properties.picture_url) {
                  picture = '<img src="' + feature.properties.picture_url + '"/>';
                } else {
                  picture = '<img class="default-img" src="default_image.png" style="visibility:hidden;"/>';
                }
                var popup = L.popup({autoPan: true, keepInView: true, maxHeight: 500, autoPanPadding: [50, 50]})
                .setContent('<div class="popup_name">' + feature.properties.name + '</div>' + '<br>' + '<div class="popup_address">' + feature.properties.address + '</div>' + '<br>' + '<br>' + '<div class="popup_description">' + feature.properties.description + '</div>' + '<br>' + '<div class="popup_picture">' + picture + '</div>');
                
                layer.bindPopup(popup);
                
              }
            }).addTo(map);

        map.on('popupclose'), function(e) {
            console.log("closing popup!!!!")
            map.setView([40.66,-73.6466], 17);
            }

    </script>

The the map is visualizing correctly and the popups are correct.  But the map is not re-centering when the popup is closed.  Can anyone tell me why this isn't working?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe because there is an error.

```
map.on('popupclose'), function(e) {
   console.log("closing popup!!!!")
   map.setView([40.66,-73.6466], 17);
}
```

and it should be

```
map.on("popupclose", function (e) {
  console.log("closing popup!!!!");
  map.setView([40.66, -73.6466], 17);
});
```

Comment: Yes, I closed the parentheses incorrectly.  Thank you!